# Event loop already running error with widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

Please help with the solution to the problem:

> QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running.

I need to create a window with a button. When you click on the button, a new window opens with the image and the clicker module, which allows you to place labels on the image and read the coordinates of these labels.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button,RadioButtons, CheckButtons
from PIL import Image
from mpl_point_clicker import clicker
 
 
 
from PIL import Image
 
def link(val):
        
        fig1 = plt.figure(2)
        axes1 = fig1.subplots()
        
        width = 400 
        height = 300
        img = Image.new( mode = "RGB", size = (width, height) )
        klicker = clicker(axes1, ["1", "2", "3", "4"], markers=["x", "o", "*", "+"],colors=['red','blue','yellow','yellow'])
        plt.show()
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
    ax = fig.subplots()
    plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.35, bottom=0.1)
 
    #---BUTTON---
    ax_start_button = plt.axes([0.5,0.01,0.3, 0.05])
    #xposition, yposition, width, height
 
    start_button = Button(ax_start_button, 'Начать работу', color ='white', hovercolor = 'grey')
    start_button.on_clicked(link)
    plt.show()
```

I tried to solve it using tread - he writes that it is impossible to place the graph not in the main thread.
I tried to close the figure, but the error is the same

Comment: i didn't find answer

Comment: That's just a warning, because you're calling `plt.show` while you're inside another `plt.show`.  The application still works, doesn't it?